# Array with strings to integers

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, type-conversion, integer

I have some trouble with an array (php, wordpress) like shown below:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "416" }
  [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "1591" }
}
```

How to convert it to an array with integers?
The problem is that values are also arrays and not values like this:

```
array(2) {
      [0] =>  "416" ,
      [1]=> "1591" 
    }
```

I'm trying to get id of some posts using get_post_meta().

It is only a piece of my code:

```
$course_product = array();
    foreach ($comment_ids as $comment_id) {
        $course_product[] = get_post_meta( intval($comment_id), '_llms_wc_product_id', true );
                    }
```

It is giving me this strange array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "416"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1591"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your meta data `_llms_wc_product_id` is itself an array. So, get the first value from it by appending `[0]`:

```
get_post_meta( intval($comment_id), '_llms_wc_product_id', true )[0]
```

Comment: Thank You very much. You are correct it is an array. I have forgotten that there were some changes in the core plugins code. Now I can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This array can looks like that:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "416"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1591"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "416"
  }
}
```

It can't be deeper and I only need values so I'm using:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $course_products);
```

to flatten it and after that it looks like:

```
    array(3) { 
[0]=> int(416) 
[1]=> int(1591) 
[2]=> int(416) 
}
```

Then I can do what I wanted.

BIG THX.

Comment: As of PHP 5.6 you can also write `array_merge(...$course_products);`.